# Using laravel presenters inside illuminate/html model forms

Tags: php, laravel

I use laravel presenters from laracasts video. Basically it doesn't matter that much. What I want is to format output data when I use `Form::model`. So, for example, I have a phone number input:

```
<div class="form-group">
   {!! Form::label('phone', 'Phone' ) !!}
   {!! Form::text('phone', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'phone']) !!}
</div>
```

In the DB I store phones in e.164 format, but when I output them I want to  display them in more readable format. But data-accessors from Laravel won't help me because inside my application I want to use e.164. If I set accessor for phone attribute than I won't be able to get e.164 inside my classes. So, instead of accessors I user presenters, but it doesn't matter that much. Let's say I want to use php `number_format` function when outputting model attributes inside `Form::text`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing forcing you to have a one to one accessor to field relationship. So you can create a formatted phone attribute to use in the form, and use the phone attribute directly from within your classes.

```
public function getFormattedPhoneAttribute()
{
    return // formatted $this->phone
}
```

If you already have the presenters set up then you can use them in your form instead of using Form::model.

```
<div class="form-group">
   {!! Form::label('phone', 'Phone' ) !!}
   {!! Form::text('phone', $user->present()->phone, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'phone']) !!}
</div>
```

Either one of these should work for you, but I would recommend you choose one: Accessors or Presenters, not both.